# Trac - site wide login

Tags: php, authentication, trac

I have got Trac installed as a subset of a larger website.  Ideally I'd like to be able to log users into trac from the main site without having to use the trac interface itself.  The main site is implemented in PHP on IIS.  Additionally if the user is logged in via Trac then I'd like to be able to offer access to other features from some of the PHP pages based upon the user privileges.

Authentication uses an htpasswd file in trac and being able to administrate users via the trac interface is useful.  Additionally the same user/pass would be used for subversion as this can use the htpasswd file.  I can't use this with IIS to do the login via a virtual path and authentication role.  I don't want to use LDAP/ActiveDirectory

It would be nice to be able to implement a login page in PHP that actually logs the user into Trac.  However I an unsure how I would add an appropriate __FORM_TOKEN field in the PHP page.  It would be fine to use the trac login page itself but after logging in, it goes to the trac wiki home page rather than the referer that I set in the form data if it is not a sub-url of the trac part of the site.

Also it would be handy to be able to query permissions for the user currently logged into trac from PHP.  Presumably this is possible via the sqlite database, but how do I know who the current user is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up generating the trac_form_token cookie myself for my PHP login form, from a sub-url of the trac root (overriding that sub-url from within IIS so that it is not handled by trac but by php instead).  Easy enough to do.

Checking the logged in user is easy enough to do if you configure trac to set the path of the trac_auth cookie to be the root of the site.  You can then access this and query the trac sqlite database from PHP to get the user name and permissions.

Then for the PHP login, you generate the trac_form_token and do a POST curl request to trac and then pass on the cookies you need from the returned response header.

EDIT: change to trac.ini to make trac_auth cookie available site-wide and not just from /trac/

```
[trac] 
auth_cookie_path = \
```

Comment: Pete! I would be interested in seeing source on how you accomplished this. I would love to duplicate this, currently i run a linux box and mostly a php / apache / mysql backend. I haven't tried to implement anything as we  are using a simple text file for auth which drives me nuts. I would love to implement a database driven login with timeouts so you cant brute force it, however my python ju-ju isn't up to par with track.

Any how, would love to hear more notes about your process. (and yess i know im 3 years late on this ;) )

Comment: @Gauthier This doesn't get around the htpasswd file used by trac in my case either but allows dual login to trac and the main site via a singe web form.  Its quite complicated really and unfortunately I can't share the source code.  It did not require any changes to the python source.  You can access the trac database using SQLite3 from PHP.  e,g, to get the trac username:
'SELECT name FROM auth_cookie WHERE cookie = "'.SQLite3::escapeString($_COOKIE['trac_auth']).'"'

Comment: @Gauthier - essentially in my database I associate a trac login with a user login and log the user into both if appropriate.  I believe there are plugins for trac login but last time I looked it was a total minefield.

Comment: @Gauthier of special note as in my answer, trac_form_token cookie is ONLY accessible from a trac/ sub-url.  Hence configuration of the server to serve the login action from that path specially.  trac_auth is then set in trac.ini to be globally applicable to the site (see edit to answer).

Comment: Thanks for the details, even though you cant give source your pointers will be invaluable.